# Page wise display is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to display records as a multiples of 5, but i am getting only the first 5 records again and again.

HomePage-slideshow.php

```
<select multiple class="form-control " id="sel2"  size="10" >
                            <?php 
                            session_start();
                            if (isset($_SESSION["min"]) || isset($_SESSION["count"])) {
                                    $time = (int)$_SESSION["min"];
                                    $something = $_SESSION["something"];
                                    $everything = $_SESSION["everything"];
                                    }
                        $count = (int)$_SESSION["count"];
                        $select_query=          "SELECT * from video_details WHERE c_something = '$something' OR c_everything = '$everything' HAVING video_min <= $time  LIMIT $count,5";
                        $select_query_run =     mysqli_query($conn,$select_query);

                        while ($select_query_array=   mysqli_fetch_array($select_query_run) )
                        {
                            echo "<option value='".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["video_question"])."' >".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["video_question"])."</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                            </select>
                            <?php 
                            $new = $count + 5;
                            $_SESSION["count"] = $new;
                            $_SESSION["min"] = $time;
                            $_SESSION["something"] = $something;
                            $_SESSION["everything"] = $everything;
                            //session_destroy();
                            ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <div class="center">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success font-30" value="I AM CURIOUS ABOUT THIS" />

                    <form id="next_page" name="next_page" method="post" action="next.php" data-ajax="false">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success font-30" id="next" name="next" value="LEARN SOMETHING ELSE" />
                    </form> 
                </div>
```

I am trying to increase the $count value when the **LEARN SOMETHING ELSE** button is pressed. It redirects to next.php where i try to reassign the increased value to count.

next.php

```
<?php 

session_start();

    $inc = (int)$_SESSION["count"];
    $time = (int)$_SESSION["min"];
    $something = $_SESSION["something"];
    $everything = $_SESSION["everything"];

echo $inc;

    $_SESSION["count"] = $inc;
    $_SESSION["min"] = $time;
    $_SESSION["something"] = $something;
    $_SESSION["everything"] = $everything;

    header("location: HomePage-slideshow.php#services-section");
```

?>

The echo statement gives 5 as output, but the query displays only the old output still. If i hardcode 5 in my query, it gives next 5 records but i am not able to dynamically change the value of $count in here.

Please help me

Comment: Try moving the echo to your HomePage file.  Echoing before a header call will break the redirect, because it'll have to send the header before printing the output.

Comment: actually i dont need that echo statement. I gave it for checking. When i print there, the value is 5 but back in my homepage, the session variable count dont turn to 5. it continuously displays the 1st five records, not moving to next 5

Comment: Posted an answer below.